# Jfrog integration with GitHub Status Checks

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I would like to have a GitHub workflow which do jfrog xray scan and integrate with GitHub status checks to determine status based on scan results?

I tried to scan and retrieve scanned results based on priority. Iam trying to see away to integrate with GitHub status checks?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should share in your question what you've tried so far (show  the workflow, even if it does not yet works 100% in your favor) and next to what you already outline, what prevents you doing so. I.e. what prevents you to make Github Status Checks?